# Sorting a list based on date in mongodb using python and tornado

Tags: python, mongodb, sorting, tornado, tornado-motor

I am trying to sort a list of students from a table in mongodb. I am using tornado and python. I am using `Motorclient` to connect with db .I am getting a proper result when using `students.find()`

```
Sid = self.body['Sid']
data = []
_id = db.students.find({"Sid": Sid},{'_id': False,"status": False,"Dateofadmission":False})
for document in (yield _id.to_list(length=100)):
    data.append(document)
return[{"status code": 1,"studentInfo": data }]
```

Now when I try to sort and list it gives me internal server error, with no error logging in the terminal.

```
_id = db.students.find({"Sid": Sid},{'_id': False,"status": False,"Dateofadmission":False}).sort({'Dateofadmission' : -1})
```

the date is stored in mongodb as:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56443dc03f32df1bf0e8b4e8"),
    "Dateofadmission" : ISODate("2015-10-22T00:00:00Z"),
    "Sid" : "56443dc03f32df1bf0e8b4e8",
    "Name" : "Ram"
}
```

Someone please guide me on how I can sort the list of students based on the `Dateofadmission`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`sort()`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html?_ga=1.182210983.1014514819.1447393203#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.sort) in `pymongo` takes two parameters - a key (or a list of keys) and the direction. Replace:

```
db.students.find({"Sid": Sid}, {'_id': False,"status": False,"Dateofadmission":False}).sort({'Dateofadmission' : -1})
```

with:

```
db.students.find({"Sid": Sid}, {'_id': False,"status": False,"Dateofadmission":False}).sort('Dateofadmission', pymongo.DESCENDING)
```